# How to add multiple video links on IOS

Tags: ios

I am beginner in android development and try to play video from link. But it's giving error "sorry,we can't play this video". I tried so many links but for all links its show same error. 
please help me friends

Comment: ur tag is `iOS` in android development. :)

Comment: you are asking android question with ios tag... What is this??